# Notification.permission in chrome always return denied

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, notifications

I have a website that asks notification permission from user during log-in. I have a code there that auto-logouts the user when he/she denies the permission (see the codes below)

```
//Checks if user browsers notification is "Allowed", if "denied", logs out user
if(Notification.permission == 'denied') {
     removeAllCookies($cookies);
     $location.path("/login");
}
```

That code seems ok at first but just today it started malfunctioning. All new users auto-logouts even if they haven't configured the permission yet.

I even tried to check the permission manually at the favicon at the left of address bar and I can see that it is still set to `ask(default)`. I also tried to manually set it to `Allow` yet the `Notification.permission` function still returns denied. What's causing this? It is ok in my pc but in all other users it auto-blocks.

EDIT: Just now I'm already experiencing the same thing on my PC. My Notification permission is Allowed but `Notification.permission` always return `denied`. I console logged it and it really does return denied. Anyone?

Comment: Do you mean it works on `localhost` but not on a different site?

Comment: no sir. What I mean is it works in my pc but auto logouts on other pc(s) that are accessing the website

Answer (score 2):

Strange business logic you've got there, but for what it's worth...

There are a few stipulations Chrome puts in place:

1) Must be using HTTPS or localhost. If you are not, it will automatically deny the permissions in my experience

2) Works more reliably if you register a service worker (I think it's actually required for mobile chrome)

Make sure to read documentation surrounding Notifications API thoroughly, as you'll learn some stuff. MDN is a great resource.

Something else that might help is ensuring you have your notification logic wrapped in the requestPermission promise:

```
Notification.requestPermission().then(function(permission) {
//if permission == 'denied' // logout
}
```

Let me know if any of this helps.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me when I changed the IP-address to localhost.

Comment: Please use chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure to define local origin as secure

Answer (score 1):

are you loading the permission inside an iframe? Seems like a chrome change, where Notification.permission will return denied if asked within an iframe

Comment: No sir, I'm using angularjs. I execute `Notification.permission` inside my page's controller so basically when I load the page that code executes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using in CodePen or JSFiddle, where code is running inside an `iframe`, the permission will always return `denied` on Windows and Linux. On macOS works fine.

- https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QomMVe
- https://jsfiddle.net/7qwdy4xb/

Answer (score 0):

The ability to call `Notification.requestPermission()` from non-main frames had been removed from Chrome since version 60, but still works fine on Firefox at time of writing.